# Can I avoid using the same $match criteria twice when using $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Take the following data as an example:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "abc",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 },
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 50 }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  item: "def",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 20 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 5 },
    { size: "M", color: "black", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "L", color: "red", quantity: 2 }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 3,
  item: "ijk",
  stock: [
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 15 },
    { size: "L", color: "blue", quantity: 100 },
    { size: "L", color: "red", quantity: 25 }
  ]
}
```

Say I'm going to filter out the `stock`s that matches the criteria `size = 'L'`. I already have a multikey index on the `stock.size` field.

In the aggregation pipeline, if I use the following two operations:

```
[{$unwind: {path: "$stock"}},
{$match: {"stock.size": "L"}}]
```

I will get the desired results, but when the db gets very large, the `$unwind` step will have to scan the whole collection, without utilizing the existing index, which is very inefficient.

If I reverse the order of the `$unwind` and `$match` operations, the `$match` will utilize the index to apply an early filtering, but the final result will not be as desired: it will fetch the extra `stock`s that are not of size L, but have sibling L-sized `stock`s that belong to the same `item`.

Would I have to use the same `$match` operation twice, i.e. both before and after the `$unwind`, to make it both utilizing the index and return the correct results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) stage twice in the aggregation pipeline but here only the first [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) stage will use the index second one will do the collscan.

```
[
    { "$match": { "stock.size": "L" }},
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$stock" }},
    { "$match": { "stock.size": "L" }}
]
```

If you want to avoid the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) twice then use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation

```
[
  { "$match": { "stock.size": "L" } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "stock": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$stock",
        "as": "st",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$stock.size", "L"] }
      }
    }
  }}
]
```